# UnicodeDecodeError in Python with codecs module

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I have a text file which comprises unicode strings "aBiyukÙwa", "varcasÙva" etc. When I try to decode them in the python interpreter using the following code, it works fine and decodes to `u'aBiyuk\xd9wa'`:

```
"aBiyukÙwa".decode("utf-8")
```

But when I read it from a file in a python program using the `codecs` module in the following code it throws a `UnicodeDecodeError`.

```
file = codecs.open('/home/abehl/TokenOutput.wx', 'r', 'utf-8')
for row in file:
```

Following is the error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 8: invalid continuation byte
```

Any ideas what is causing this strange behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your file is not encoded in UTF-8. Find out what it *is* encoded in, and then use that.

Comment: Ù is 0xD9 in ISO8859-[1,3,10,14-16].